# Finding Total Impedence

Tags: capacitor, inductor, circuit-design, transimpedance

So I know how to solve parallel circuits but I am struggling when they are not in the form of resistors rather capacitance.

So I believe the form for this circuit would be:
Zt= 100+ ((200||1.33j)||(.377))

So would it be:

100+ (((200)(1.33j)/(200+1.33j))
100+ (.0088+1.33j)

So:

100+ ((.0088+1.33j)(.377j)/(.0088+1.707j))

Zt= 100 + .3j

Seems like the right work but numbers seem off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYwGhx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you wanting a DC resistance, or something with a time-domain component? At DC, the inductor effectively becomes shorted, relegating any current flowing to/through the cap & 200ohm resistor to being "negligible." However, with the parallel LC circuit in there, you would likely have some *very* interesting things going on for the first few resonance cycles after the power was suddenly turned on or off.

Comment: For the question we are neglecting the power source and just wants the total impedance of the system (circuit). Wants it in Zt= Req+Rj

Comment: This can't be properly answered without knowing the working frecuency...

Comment: It's just wanting to know the total impedance of the system. I got the answer 100+.3j do not know if it's right tho.

Answer (score 1):

Should be \$\small -jX_C\$ and \$\small jX_L\$ in the first equation; presumably \$\small -j1.33\$ and \$\small j0.377\$ if the reactances are correct (operating frequency is not given in question, but I guess it's 60 Hz).

Works out at around: \$\small Z_t=100+j0.38\$.

Comment: So my answer is close to this. When you are getting the parallel impedance are you using Zc=Zl*Zr/(Zl+Zr)?  So would be (200)(1.33j)/(200+1.33j). Then do it again for the other parallel part (.377j)

Comment: Easier to calculate the reactances in parallel first, then put the result in parallel with the 200

Comment: Reactances meaning the capacitor and inductor? Hmm I ran threw the numbers again I mean yours is close but I still keep getting 100+j.53. So I'll stick with that one. Do you know how to do my other problem I was struggling with? It's a complex load transformer and it was wanting load impedance, primary current, and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

To get the impedance, you must know the frequency.  However, if we assume 60Hz for this case, we get the following impedances:
  Zc=0-j1.326;  Zl=0+j0.377; Z2=200.  The parallel combination of these three (by adding the admittances and then taking the reciprocal) is Zp=0.00138+j0.5267.  The total input Impedance (at 60 Hz) is 100+j0.527.